# Lookahead, lookbehind condition in regular expression

Tags: php, regex, pcre, regex-lookarounds

The following example is about using lookahead assertion as a condition. I found it in the PHP manual at: http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.conditional.php

```
(?(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])
\d{2}-[a-z]{3}-\d{2}  |  \d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2} )
```

Here's the description about this regex:

> The condition is a positive lookahead assertion that matches an optional sequence of non-letters followed by a letter. In other words, it tests for the presence of at least one letter in the subject. If a letter is found, the subject is matched against the first alternative; otherwise it is matched against the second. This pattern matches strings in one of the two forms dd-aaa-dd or dd-dd-dd, where aaa are letters and dd are digits.

Could anyone tell me why we use lookahead assertion as the condition in this example? Why don't we use lookbehind assertion? I get confused when they're used as conditions like this because I don't know how do they match the subject string. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In this case we're using a lookahead assertion to decide which regex to use. It looks like it's deciding between matching dates of the form `01-Jan-12` and `01-01-12`. The lookahead assertion sees if there are any letters within what we're trying to match and if so uses the `\d{2}-[a-z]{3}-\d{2}` to try and match `01-Jan-12` if not it uses `\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}` to try and match `01-01-12`.

Comment: Could you explain my second question: why don't we use lookbehind assertion in this case?

Comment: Because we want to know *beforehand* which regex we need to use. If we use lookbehind at the beginning of the string there's nothing to match and after that point we've lost some of the data we want to match.